# Floyd rose changes Pitch

Tags: electric-guitar

My guitar equipped with a Floyd Rose changes the pitch, when the Position is changed. I.e. tune it sitting down, and when i stand up the pitch is lower. What is wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you tune it standing up?

Comment: And how much does it go out of tune?

Comment: About 1/4th of a note

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyzTJ-R89KI Herman Li from Dragonforce goes over this issue in this video.

Comment: Great video, thanks! So this is pretty normal

Answer (score 1):

If the pitch is getting lower, you will need to tighten the coils in the back of the guitar with a screwdriver.
You will have to do some experimentation until you find the sweet spot that balances the tension between the front of the guitar caused by the strings and the tension on the back caused by the coils.

They will probably need to be adjusted as well if you change the thickness or type of strings.

Hope it helps